# How to use elements retrieved from selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to I effectively use elements retrieved from Selenium that are stored in variables?  I am using python. In the program below:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://boards.4chan.org/wg/archive")
matching_threads = []
key = "Pixel"
for i in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("teaser-col"):
    if key in i.text:
        matching_threads.append(i)
        matched_thread = i
print(matching_threads)
driver.quit()
```

I get the following from the printout of matching_threads:
`[<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="aa74a4a6-5bb2-4b48-92b6-50f5d51a9e5c", element="59b6076f-a5a2-4862-9c1f-028025e4b567")>]`

How can I use that output to select said element in selenium and interact with it?  What I am trying to do is goto that element and then click on the element to the right of it.  What I am failing to understand is how to retrieve the element in selenium using the stored information in matching_threads.

If anyone can help me, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Loop through and use x.find_element and so forth with a click().

Comment: Loop through matching_threads you mean?  Or loop through `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("teaser-col"):`?

Comment: If you want to loop through that and find its child element. i.find_element_by_xpath(".//").click() would be what you would do. You could loop either.

Comment: Actually I am wanting to find the element beside it, not the child element.  In the image below the elements I am finding from the for loop have a class of "teaser-col" and the element I want to click on has a class of "quotelink". So I am finding the right row with the key and need to click on the element beside the one with the text "Pixel art wallpapers"  https://imgur.com/kWKpYAF.png

Comment: .//following::td[1]/a[@class='quotelink'] would be the right xpath to the element.

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much, I was even able to store it as a variable!  I guess you can store elements as variables and access them in selenium.

Comment: Just watch out in case the clicks open up a new page. Stale elements and so forth.

Comment: You are correct!  I had to move the click outside of the for loop otherwise it would try and reference stale elements.  Is there another site you use for selenium docs?  There's a lot I can't find on the official docs page. Also thanks so much for the help, how do I give you rep?

Comment: It's mostly from trail and error from answering a ton of selenium questions.

Comment: You can accept the answer by checkmarking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the next opposing td with an a tag with class quotelink.

```
i.find_element_by_xpath(".//following::td[1]/a[@class='quotelink']").click()
```

Now if the page moves to another you could just grab the href value, insert them into an array and than loop through them with and use driver.get(). If it opens a new tab you should be fine.

```
.get_attribute('href')
```